# Below code is not handelling new window in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

To handle multiple windows I have written below code. Its not giving me any error, however no action is getting performed on new window. Can you please help me to fix this issue or suggest me any other way. Thanks!

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    FirefoxDriver dw2 = new FirefoxDriver();

    dw2.get("http://quercus0638v.quercus.kpn.org:90");


    //OPEN login and provide credentials
    dw2.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    dw2.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_GebruikersnaamTextBox")).clear();        
    dw2.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_GebruikersnaamTextBox")).sendKeys("behdse");   
    dw2.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_WachtwoordTextBox")).clear();
    dw2.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_WachtwoordTextBox")).sendKeys("fiet$hok");

    //Login   : Clcik on Login button
    dw2.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_LoginButton")).click();        


    //Click on Select button.  After that new window will open
     dw2.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_CWDatumRadioButton")).click();

     // Below code I written to get the window handles
     Set<String> AllWindowHandles = dw2.getWindowHandles();
        String window1 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[0];
        System.out.print("window1 handle code = "+AllWindowHandles.toArray()[0]);
        String window2 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[1];
        System.out.print("\nwindow2 handle code = "+AllWindowHandles.toArray()[1]);


       //Switch to window2(child window) and performing actions on it.
       dw2.switchTo().window(window2);


     //Click the user
     dw2.findElement(By.id("AfdelingGebruikersListView_RowCheckBox_8")).click();

    //Click on OK button after selecting User
     dw2.findElement(By.id("AfdelingGebruikersListView_OKButton")).click();


   //Switch to window1(child window) and performing actions on it.
     dw2.switchTo().window(window1);

    //Click the order type you want to retrieve
     dw2.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_VerwerktRadioButton")).click();

    //Click for exporting the data to Excel Sheet
     dw2.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_ExporteerNaarExcelButton")).click();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Editing the Code as per the comment by OP :-**

Since, as I suggested in comment, **it might not be a new window. It must be a pop-up.** So, please **replace your code as below and try**:

```
//Click on Select button.  After that new window will open
dw2.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_CWDatumRadioButton")).click()

//Click the user
try{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(dw2,20);
    WebElement ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("AfdelingGebruikersListView_RowCheckBox_8")));
    ele.click();
}catch(Throwable e){
    System.err.println("Error while clicking on the element. "+e.getMessage());
}

//Click on OK button after selecting User
dw2.findElement(By.id("AfdelingGebruikersListView_OKButton")).click();
```

Comment: Hello Friends, Unfortunately above codes are not working. No error message is displayed however not identifying second window. 
I would like to share some more details that could help to understand the exact problem which I am facing.
**Below are my observations:**
When new window is created then on task bar it displayed the two instances of the browser window like below highlighted in Red box:
However in my case new window is open, task bar still shows only one instance of browser. 
I am not sure whether this is a frame or new window. Can you please help me to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: If this is a public site, please share the URL. Or else, please add the image related to the windows. Since, you don't have enough reputation, please upload your image in [imgur](http://imgur.com/), and share the link here. Then it will be easier to comprehend, what you're getting at. Thanks. :)

Comment: Hi Subh, I am not able to upload image on this site as this blocked to me. Is there any other way, that I can send you the attachment. Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Like I said, [please use imgur](http://imgur.com/) to upload the screenshot/attachment and add its link here, so that I can access it..

Comment: I have uploaded image for both above stated observation. Please have a look.                 http://imgur.com/dTFPIlG

Comment: Do one thing. After the code that results in the opening of new window, i.e., `dw2.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_CWDatumRadioButton")).click();`, add this code: `System.out.println("Total window handles: "+dw2.getWindowHandles().size();)`. Let me know what it returns: **'2' or '1'**.

Comment: It's giving the value as '1'. Sorry for the late reply as I was out of office for 4 days. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Okay.. Then the suspected new window, is infact, a popup embedded in the same window. You can directly access it without switching to it. Please try my edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks Subh, I tried with above code however the original problem is still persists... like script is not failing but not performing any action on pop up.

Comment: If this is this a public site, can you please provide me the URL so that I can look into it ?

Comment: unfortunately it worked only on client network, can not share with you. :(

Answer (score 0):

U can switch to windows using:

```
for (String winHandle : objDriver.getWindowHandles()) {
        objDriver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
```

This will switch to the last window opened. To get back to parent window by again using the above code. It would be better that u incorporate the code in a different method in order to reuse.

Hope this helps. Thanks.